# Extracting wanted words from multiple text files (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a folder with ~100 000 txt files. I'm trying to read all files and create a DataFrame with two columns id and text. For the id I'm taking numbers from my file name, for example, file BL2334_uyhjghbvbvhf, I'm extracting everything before underscore so in this example my id is BL2334. Before creating a data frame I would like to extract only words in Detected Text: ... So in this file word BUCK, NIP, Preerfal Deet Attracter.

**My file:**

```
Id: 02398123-a642-4e3f-88a7
Type: LINE
Detected Text: BUCK
Confidence: 77.965172
Id: c85bbbe
Type: LINE
Detected Text: NIP
Confidence: 97.186539
Id: 28926a7a-78024c80-b9c5
Type: LINE
Detected Text: Preerfal Deet Attracter
Confidence: 47.749722
```

**My code:**

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Users\example\Documents\MyFolder'

file_list = []

for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
        file_list.append([root + "\\" + file for file in files])
def flatten(file_list):
    result_list_files = []
    for element in file_list:
        if isinstance(element, str):
            result_list_files.append(element)
        else:
            for element_1 in flatten(element):
                result_list_files.append(element_1)
    return result_list_files 
result_flatten = flatten(file_list)

final_df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in result_flatten:
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
    id = file.split('\\')[-1].split('_')[0]
    temp_df['id'] = [id]
    temp_df['text'] = [open(file,encoding="utf8").read()]
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, temp_df], ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: I'm getting an output with two columns id and text. This is taking a long time and in my text column I have everitjing from my file and I need just words from Detecte Text:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expanding the @Luca Angioioni' solution, you can use something like:

```py
import os
import re

data = {'id': [], 'text': []}

for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        data['id'].append(file.split('_')[0])
        with open(os.path.join(root, file)) as f:
            data['text'].append(re.findall('Detected Text: (.*)\n', f.read()))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

where it will return an id with a list of matchs in `text` per row. You can always use `df.explode('text')` to explode the matches to their own rows, with duplicated ids, though.

---

If you don't want to use `re` for some reason, you can replace the last line by:

```
data['text'].append([line.split(':')[1].strip() for line in f if line.startswith('Detected Text')])
```

and it should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

- To only get the `Detected Text` parts I would use a regular expression. Example:

  ```
  import re

  text = """
  Id: 02398123-a642-4e3f-88a7
  Type: LINE
  Detected Text: BUCK
  Confidence: 77.965172
  Id: c85bbbe
  Type: LINE
  Detected Text: NIP
  Confidence: 97.186539
  Id: 28926a7a-78024c80-b9c5
  Type: LINE
  Detected Text: Preerfal Deet Attracter
  Confidence: 47.749722
  """

  pattern = re.compile(r"Detected Text: (.*)\n")
  match = pattern.findall(text)  # match becomes ['BUCK', 'NIP', 'Preerfal Deet Attracter']
  ```
- One thing that makes your code slower is the fact that you keep allocating new Dataframes and then you concatenate them. One way around this could be to create a dictionary first with `key = id, value = text` and then convert it to a DF using the `from_dict` method: [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html). Or you could use a list of tuples like this `(id, text)` and then just:

  ```
  tuples = [
  ("id1", "some text")
  ("id2", "some other text")
  ...
  ]
  final_df = pd.DataFrame(tuples, columns=['id', 'text'])
  ```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand your solution. Before final_df = pd.DataFrame()
I need to create dictionary?

Comment: @DinkoJantoš No, in your `for file in result_flatten:` do not create a df, but append to a dictionary, or even list of tuples... whatever. Then only at the end of the for loop you convert it to a data frame. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you for your help.